# When using python Tkinter, how can I stop two entry box's in the same class showing the same input text?

Tags: python, text, tkinter, field, tkinter-entry

I am having this issue with Python Tkinter. I am trying to make a user interface form screen which requires the user to enter values into entry box's displayed on screen. I have set it so the two Entry Box's are in the same class (that class being the interface screen). The problem is that while I type into one of the box's, the text which I type not only displays in the box in which I am typing into, but also in the other box.

Below is the code in question.

```
class GenericSkeleton: # The template for all the screens in the program

    def __init__(self): 

        self.GenericGui = Tk()
        self.GenericGui.title('Radial Arc Calculator')
        self.GenericGui.geometry('360x540')
        self.GenericGui.resizable(width = FALSE, height = FALSE)
        Label(self.GenericGui,text = 'Radial Arc Calculator',font = ('Ariel',18)).place(x=65,y=35)

    def destroy(self):

        self.GenericGui.destroy()



class InputScreen(GenericSkeleton):

    def __init__(self):  

        GenericSkeleton.__init__(self)

        Button(self.GenericGui,text = 'CALCULATE',height = 1, width = 25, command = calculate, font = ('TkDefaultFont',14)).place(x=37,y=400)
        Button(self.GenericGui,text = 'CLOSE',height = 1, width = 11, command = close, font = ('TkDefaultFont',14)).place(x=37, y=450)
        Button(self.GenericGui,text = 'HELP', height = 1, width = 11, command = DisplayHelp, font = ('TkDefaultFont',14)).place(x=190, y=450)

        Label(self.GenericGui,text = 'Enter Radius (mm):', font = ('TkDefaultFont',14)).place(x=37, y=180)
        Label(self.GenericGui,text = 'Enter point distance (mm):', font = ('TkDefaultFont',14)).place(x=37, y=250)

        Entry(self.GenericGui,textvariable = Radius, width = 10, font = ('TkDefaultFont',14)).place(x=210, y=180)
        Entry(self.GenericGui,textvariable = Distance, width = 5, font = ('TkDefaultFont',14)).place(x=265, y=250)    

run = InputScreen()
```

The entry box's are at the bottom of the code, I hope its enough/not too much to solve the problem.

Comment: Where are `Radius` and `Distance` defined?  Do you have something like        `Radius = Distance = StringVar()` in your code?

Comment: @Jkdc I have `Radius = int(0)` and `Distance = int(0)` at the top of my code as initialization. The data is of integer type, could I use `Radius = Distance = IntVar()`? And where should I place it, inside or outside the class?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that they both share the same `textvariable` (you use different variable names, but they have the same value which makes them the same in the eyes of tkinter). My advice is to not use the `textvariable` attribute. You don't need it.

However, if you remove the use of `textvariable` then you need to separate your widget creation from widget layout so that you can keep a reference to the widget. Then you can use the `get` method on the widget (rather than on the variable) to get the value:

```
self.entry1 = Entry(...)
self.entry2 = Entry(...)
self.entry1.place(...)
self.entry2.place(...)
```

Later, you can get the values like this:

```
radius = int(self.entry1.get())
distance = int(self.entry2.get())
```

If you do need the `textvariable` (usually only if you're using the `trace` feature of a tkinter variable), you must use a tkinter variable (`StringVar`, `IntVar`, etc) rather than a regular variable.

Comment: Thank you, this has fixed the problem, but I am very new to Tkinter, how else could I have the value typed into each box assigned to a variable which I can then use for calculations/algorithms?

Could I just do `Radius = Entry(self.GenericGui, width = 10, font = ('TkDefaultFont',14)).place(x=210, y=180)
        Distance = Entry(self.GenericGui, width = 5, font = ('TkDefaultFont',14)).place(x=265, y=250)` etc?

Comment: @Josh23761: if you use `textvariable`, you must use `the_variable.get()` to get the value. If you don't use `textvariable`, you must use `the_widget.get()`. Either way requires a function call. At least without the `textvariable` you have one less object that you have to manage.

Comment: @BryanOakley Thank you very much for the help, I much appreciate it. In the future I will use this method.